# Cuda 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010 cl compiler error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

As I did not get any help in the [Nvidia forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?s=694d90b48a2678063a619d0ed138f76d&showtopic=207820) (see my post at the bottom of the thread), and it seems I am not the only one struggeling with similar problems, I will give it a try here.

I tried to compile the Cuda SDK 4.0 examples as well as following the very nice [tutorial by Ade Miller](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/05/visual-studio-2010-and-cuda-easier-with-rc2/). But compiling the ".cu" file won't work.

This is the (exemplary) command the compiler invokes:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\bin\nvcc.exe" 
-gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env 
--cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC bin\x86_amd64"  
-I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include"  -G0  
--keep-dir "x64\Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile  -D_NEXUS_DEBUG 
-g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MDd " -o "x64\Debug\Hello.cu.obj" 
"D:\Code\CUDA\Test_Cuda_4_0\Test_Cuda_4_0\Hello.cu"
```

And this is the strange error message I always get.

```
nvcc fatal   : Compiler 'cl' in PATH different than the one specified with -ccbin
```

**EDIT**: To be a bit more precise: Visual Studio just tells me the command did not succeed ("exit code -1") -> to see this error message I have to invoke the command by myself in the command line.

1) Why should `nvcc` care about the path in the environment variable differing from the one specified with the command line option? If it would care, wouldn't this make the command line option completely useless?

2) How to fix ;) ?

I use Win7 64Bit, VS2010 Prof SP1, and the following nvidia versions:
cudatoolkit_4.0.17_win_64
devdriver_4.0_winvista-win7_64_270.81_general
gpucomputingsdk_4.0.19_win_64

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the win32 target build ok? What changes did you make when you added the x64 target? Fair enough you're not the only one but many others have never seen this on the same platform (including me) so just trying to get more information.

Comment: Win32 build doesn't work either. For the 64bit version I just added (see Ade Miller's tutorial) '64-bit (--machine 64)' in the config properties (Cuda c/c++ -> target machine platform).

Answer (score 1):

try using the conventional method to start writing a CUDA program, as given in Getting Started guide(Copy the sample). To solve the above problem you have to add it as an environment variable. But since the SDK samples are already linked, they don't give problems.

Comment: As I said I get the same error when I try to compile the SDK samples.
In the beginning I followed exactly the "Getting started" guide I found under: C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\C\doc\CUDA_C_Getting_Started_Windows.pdf. At the stage "compile one of the SDK samples" I got stuck with the error reported above.

Comment: Actually, even I get this error when I compile from cmd, but it works fine in vs2010. Did you consider reinstalling the sdk and toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. previously i copied `cl.exe` in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin` for test several parameters with `nvcc.exe` and forget delete this file from this directory. i removed this file and everything is OK. purpose of `PATH` for my problem in really was for this path: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin` and wasn't `PATH` in Environment variables.